# mysqli prepared statement wont login

Tags: php, html, authentication, mysqli

For some reason i keep trying to login and keep getting my error, that the username and password is invalid. Ive tried hard setting the password in the coding instead of using the post method. Anyone got any ideas?

also, i KNOW md5 is NO GOOD anymore, but idc about that right now, i'll be switching to SHA-2 once all my functionallity is done, and i'll salt and hash it at a later point.

```
<?php
include_once"dbconnection.php";
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=? LIMIT 1")) 
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
            $stmt->fetch();
            if($stmt->fetch() == true)
            {
                $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
                header('Location: blogzone.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
            }
            $stmt->close(); 
        }
        else 
        {   

        }
    }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

My HTML

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login">
   <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `SHA-2` isn't really any more secure than `md5` for password hashing. You should be using something like `bcrypt` if possible.

Comment: Try printing out the `$email` and `$password` in your query to make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: i replaced the  echo "Wrong Username or Password!"; with printf("%s %s\n", $email, $password); and got no results black just a blank screen

Answer (score 1):

You already call `fetch()` once on the *mysqli statement* object then call on it again in your `if` condition.

```
        $stmt->fetch();            // <---- Notice you already fetched the result
        if($stmt->fetch() == true) // <---- This is your problem right here
        {
            /* ... */
        } else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
        }
```

Note that once you fetch the result there no more rows left to fetch then `mysqli_stmt::fetch` will return `NULL`. Don't fetch it the first time if you want to check the result in your `if` condition or store the result of the call to `mysqli_stmt::fetch` in a variable and check that instead.

Comment: I couldnt seem to get it working with what your saying. But i do get where your going with it and keeping a NULL value... any other suggestions? Do you have a sample of how to use the mysqli_stmt::fetch? Im fairly new to mysqli

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the required parameters are not being fetched.
Try this code(Untested)

```
<?php
include_once"dbconnection.php";
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=? AND  password=? LIMIT 1");
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
            {
                while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

                  {$_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                   $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
                   header('Location: blogzone.php');
                   exit();
                   }

            }
            else {
                echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
        else 
        {   

        }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: @AaronRussell Have you already stored the password in the `user` table as MD5 hash?

Comment: yes they WERE stored as MD5, then when i went to do a test i changed the password through phpmyadmin and got the proper login cred.. now i just dont know how to logout so i can re test it... lol

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got your answer but try this:

print out the hashed version of the user's password that they insert in the login form (not from the database) and see if they match.

`echo md5($_POST['password']);`

It might help determine. Say if the one in the database matched but was missing strings at the end, you'd know you didn't set your varchar to be big enough for the row in the database.